# Want to delete a zip file I sent

Tags: gmail

I sent a large zip file to a friend that contained family photographs and other documents.  Apparently it was too large and put into some "place" where the receiver had to set up a login or register or something (Gmail).  Where is this file now and can I delete it or stop it from being opened?

Comment: Sounds like the zip was probably added to your Google Drive.  Can you confirm that's what the message said?

Answer (score 1):

Open the sent message. It's very likely that it will include a link to your file.

An alternative is to go directly to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com).